# How to load a FOR XML SQL query into an ADO recordset

Tags: sql-server, xml, asp-classic

I need to post an order from a SQL Server database to an XML based order system.

I have written a (complex) SQL query using the `FOR XML` statement.

I need to retrieve the query data and then post it to the web page for the ordering system.

I found code on the MSDN site to read the XML into an ADO.datastream, and then display it to the

```
Dim adoConn

Set adoConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

Dim sConn

sConn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=(local);" & _
        "Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
adoConn.ConnectionString = sConn

adoConn.CursorLocation = adUseClient

adoConn.Open
Dim adoCmd
Set adoCmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set adoCmd.ActiveConnection = adoConn
Dim sQuery
sQuery = "<ROOT xmlns:sql='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-sql'><sql:query>SELECT Demographics from Sales.Store WHERE CustomerID = 3 FOR XML AUTO</sql:query></ROOT>"

Dim adoStreamQuery

Set adoStreamQuery = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
adoStreamQuery.Open

adoStreamQuery.WriteText sQuery, adWriteChar

adoStreamQuery.Position = 0

adoCmd.CommandStream = adoStreamQuery

adoCmd.Dialect = "{5D531CB2-E6Ed-11D2-B252-00C04F681B71}"

adoCmd.Properties("Output Stream") = Response

Response.write "<XML ID='MyDataIsle'>"

adoCmd.Execute , , 1024

Response.write "</XML>"
```

I've tried to remove this code:

```
adoCmd.Properties("Output Stream") = Response
```

and then change the Execute statement so it is set to a recordset

ie

```
set rsCurrent = adoCommand.Execute
```

but I get an error when it tries to execute that statement.

Assuming I can get that to work, I don't understand if the recordset is going to have a single record with my entire XML in it, or if there will be one record per line in the XML result.

Thank you

Comment: If your using "FOR XML", wouldn't you want to load your output into a MSXML2.DOMDocument object rather than a recordset object?

Comment: Maybe... I hadn't read about that option. I don't have that DLL installed so I will try to download that and see how I make out.  Thank you

Comment: You should have it, it's standard on a Windows server. It's not something you need to install separately.

Comment: To call the most recent version, use `Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")`